# How to click on the anchor element when the spinner obscures it using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am new to selenium and i have been trying for some time to click on an anchor element. I have tried css-selector,lint_text,xpath,absolute xpath but i am still unable to click on it and instead i am getting this error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: Driver Schedule
```

Does anyone know how to get around this ?

Update: I am getting this error now:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <a href="#/schedule/weekly-view"> is not clickable at point (326,333) because another element <div class="app-spinner-layer active"> obscures it
```

Comment: Do _not_ post code as pictures.

Comment: Check if your element is inside any <iframe>. in that case you need to switch to that frame then your driver object will be able to click that element.

Comment: Actually it's an admin panel, the code contains password, which i can't share, i can share the rest of the code.

Comment: No <iFrame> @NitishKshirsagar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `click()` on the element with text as **Driver Schedule** as it is an **`<a>`** node you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.app-spinner-layer.active")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Driver Schedule"))).click()
  ```
- Using `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='app-spinner-layer active']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Driver Schedule"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.app-spinner-layer.active")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.pll a[href$='weekly-view']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='app-spinner-layer active']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href,'weekly-view') and contains(., 'Driver Schedule')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I am getting this error now: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <a href="#/schedule/weekly-view"> is not clickable at point (326,333) because another element <div class="app-spinner-layer active"> obscures it

Comment: @MohammadTaha Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.