# Verify element not present in the DOM

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I am currently trying to verify that the element is not present in the DOM:  I have written this function:

```
element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)     
if element.is_displayed():         
    raise Exception("Element should not be found")     
else:
    pass
```

I am receiving message:

```
Unable to locate element
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use ***find_elements_by_xpath***.

```
if len(self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)) > 0:         
    raise Exception("Element should not be found")     
else:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

[`is_displayed()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=displayed#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_displayed) only checks whether the element is shown to the user (visible) - not the existence.

Also [`find_element_by_xpath()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=displayed#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath) raises an [`NoSuchElementException`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=displayed#selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException) when an element is not found, so you should wrap the whole code with `try/catch` as the following

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)     
    if element.is_displayed():         
        raise Exception("Element should not be found")     
    else:
        print("element is not shown")
except NoSuchElementException:
        print("element doesn't exist in the tree")
```

Answer (score 0):

To verify that the element is not present in the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `invisibility_of_element_located()` and you can use the following logic:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "xpath")))
    print("Element no more found")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Element should not be found")
```

Note : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to click on the anchor element when the spinner obscures it using Selenium and Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59658236/how-to-click-on-the-anchor-element-when-the-spinner-obscures-it-using-selenium-a/59659543#59659543)