# When using selenium and Python how do I set a wait condition that checks that none of the div elements has an ID that contains a certain string?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

This is an example of  XPATH to count the elements
`$x("count(//div[contains(text(),'domain')])")`  ◄ you can test this in the browser
The below code should work if the wait condition is satisfied (find a "p" tag where the text contains "domain".

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless") # Ensure GUI is off
webdriver_service = Service("/home/myuser/geckodriver/geckodriver")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
# Get element with tag name 'div'
xpath_count_condition="bolean(count(//p[contains(text(), 'domain')])==1)"
browser.get("https://www.example.com")
wait=WebDriverWait(browser, 3).until(lambda browser: 
browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value=xpath_count_condition))   
element = browser.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'lulu')

# Get all the elements available with tag name 'p'
elements = element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'p')
for e in elements:
    print(e.text)
```

**I am getting this error**
`InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given xpath expression "bolean(count(//p[contains(text(), 'domain')])==1)" is invalid: SyntaxError: Document.evaluate: The expression is not a legal expression`

I would expect that once the above works I can turn that into a negative search (count==0) hence the subject line which is what I am after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To wait for all the *`<div>`* elements with an ID not to contain a certain string you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*invisibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59659543/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@id, 'domain')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [Selenium Explicit Waits for invisibility_of_element() not waiting at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70211530/7429447)

Comment: shouldn't //div[contains(., 'domain')] actually be //div[contains(@id, 'domain')] if I want to test if the ID contains the string "domain" ?

Comment: @MiniMe My bad, corrected it now, thanks for the feedback.