# How to click on a button continuously until another element appears using Selenium Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I have a website which has a button "show more", which one can click as often as one likes. At some point, there will be a `<span>` with same name and as soon as I see that one, I want to stop clicking the button.

Unfortunately, when clicking the button, it takes some moments until everything is expanded and the button is visible again. During that moment, the tag `"aria-busy="true"` is set.

So at the moment, my code works but I wait 10 seconds until I hit the button again. That is far too long, but of course, if I set this too low, the operation can fail.

My current code is this:

```
# Params: url, button-class, span_label
waiting_time = 10
options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, waiting_time)
button = wait.until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, button-class))
)
while True:
    try:
        button.click()
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, span_label)))
        logging.debug("Found last block, continue")
        break  # Exit the loop if the span element is found
    except TimeoutException:
        continue  # Continue clicking the button if the span element is not found within the timeout

content = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
```

I already use WebDriverWait, but that one does not do implicit wait for me. Also, I have the feeling that this looping approach is quite bad.

So my question is: Is there more efficient and better code for clicking the button until the span appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To continue clicking on the <kbd>show more</kbd> button untill the `<span>` appears you can induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*invisibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70211530/7429447) of the `<span>` and then induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) as follows:

```
while True:
    try:
        wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, span_label)))
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, button-class)).click()
        continue # Continue clicking the button if the span element is not found within the timeout
    except TimeoutException:
        logging.debug("Found the span, break")
        break

content = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly. One should maybe put a sleep with small time window before continue so it wont spam the website extremely

Comment: @Klinger Yeap, you can make certain tweaks keeping the logic intact.