# Click on a webelement using Selenium and onclick attribute

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am having trouble using selenium and using CSS select for onclick.

The HTML code looks like this:

```
<div class="hexagon pointer" onclick="login.LoginCACSynchro('SYNCHRO');">
```

My current code looks like this:

```
Synchro = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[onclick^='login.LoginCACSynchro('SYNCHRO');']")
```

Not sure what I a doing wrong here, any help would be very appreciated!

---

### Update

It looks like it wants to work but I am getting this error:

```
Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="hexagon pointer" onclick="login.LoginCACSynchro('SYNCHRO');">...</div> is not clickable at point (651, 543). Other element would receive the click: <div id="loader2" style="opacity: 0.627993;">...</div> (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.134)
```

Comment: Did you try to scroll the page to that element, to make sure it's in view? You can do it by executing Javascript, with `browser.execute_script('...')`. First scroll to that element, then click on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the element you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.hexagon.pointer[onclick^='login'][onclick*='LoginCACSynchro'][onclick*='SYNCHRO']").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='hexagon pointer' and starts-with(@onclick, 'login')][contains(@onclick, 'LoginCACSynchro') and contains(@onclick, 'SYNCHRO')]").click()
  ```

---

### Update

As per your comment update to click on the element:

- First induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the [*invisibility_of_element*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59658236/how-to-click-on-the-anchor-element-when-the-spinner-obscures-it-using-selenium-a/59659543#59659543)
- Then induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) as follows:

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#loader2")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.hexagon.pointer[onclick^='login'][onclick*='LoginCACSynchro'][onclick*='SYNCHRO']"))).click()
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='loader2']"))) 
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='hexagon pointer' and starts-with(@onclick, 'login')][contains(@onclick, 'LoginCACSynchro') and contains(@onclick, 'SYNCHRO')]"))).click()
    ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Hey both did not work, getting error message Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@class='hexagon pointer' and contains(@onclick, 'LoginCACSynchro')]"}

Comment: This is the whole HTML code   <div class="hexagon pointer" onclick="login.LoginCACSynchro('SYNCHRO');">

Comment: It looks like it wants to work but I am getting this error: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="hexagon pointer" onclick="login.LoginCACSynchro('SYNCHRO');">...</div> is not clickable at point (651, 543). Other element would receive the click: <div id="loader2" style="opacity: 0.627993;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.134)

Comment: Maybe this button is unclickable?  Using the python script provided and the imports and still getting the same error not clickable point.

Comment: Is it possible I can screen share and see if what I a telling you could be off?  If we find the answer I can check mark it on here.

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.

Comment: The room says this : You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq.

Comment: Gimme a moment, I guess I nailed the issue.

Comment: I used both, I am still getting the same error with the ID = Loader 2

Comment: That was bad, typo, corrected the error. Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Unfortunately both did not work, getting the exact same error with the ID = Loader2.

Comment: Seems now you are messing up, your earlier comment `<div id="loader2" style="opacity: 0.627993;">...</div>` (lower l) but now you mentioned `ID = Loader2` (upper L)

Comment: No doubt it could be me the the error I am seeing is the sameMessage: element click intercepted: Element <div class="hexagon pointer" onclick="login.LoginCACSynchro('SYNCHRO');">...</div> is not clickable at point (651, 543). Other element would receive the click: <div id="loader2" style="opacity: 0.612135;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.134)

Comment: Any chance there is a possible screen share so you can see exactly what is going on?  Again I appreciate your time and the help!

Comment: Of coarse there are. Look around

Comment: I meant specifically if you could help, and the screen share. I promise it will not take long.

Comment: I have tried, and looked around been working on this for a while now and you have gotten me along the farthest.  Sorry for the persistence, this button is the first button that needs to be clicked on the page. I still have more to do after this.

Comment: Hey there, if I add time.sleep(10) before the WebDriverWait it works. There is a Agreement banner that pops up, once you hit agree with the added time.sleep() the code recongnizes the button.  Any way around the agreement banner popup?

Comment: From your comment `<div id="loader2" style="opacity: 0.627993;">` indicated a loader which I have taken care of through `invisibility_of_element()` but had no idea of the **Agreement banner**. Glad to help you out.

Comment: Ahh got ya, the site is unique the agreement banner shows up then after that the page loads.  There is a huge loading icon that slowly fades away to the screen where the link needs to be clicked.  Again thanks for the help!