# How to handle Selenium when is_displayed attribute throws ElementNotFoundException error when page is refreshed

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriverwait, loader, nosuchelementexception

I am trying to wait for the loading spinner to finish loading and then perform some operation

My Code looks like

```
try:
    while driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.content-container div.content-element-container > div.loading-container").is_displayed()  == True:
    time.sleep(10) 
    driver.refresh()
    if count > 3:
         print("Could not fetch content")
         exit(1)
    count += 1
except Exception as e:
         print(str(e))
```

the reason for driver refresh is because of signal-r. For some reason the i do not get the data and the load spinner keeps on loading and then prints "Could Not fetch content").

If I refresh the page then I get `NoSuchElementException`. What would be the best way to handle such a scenario?

Comment: When you use is_displayed() Selenium first tries to find the element and then checks if it's displayed. If it cannot, you will get NoSuchElementException. It is better to use Selenium Expectedconditions to wait for an element to be displayed. Let me know if you need an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

```
(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.content-container div.content-element-container > div.loading-container")
```

represents the ***loading spinner*** / ***loader*** element. So on every `refresh()` the ***loader*** element will resurface again and again.

---

### Solution

An elegant approach to get past the ***loading spinner*** will be to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*`invisibility_of_element_located()`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59659543/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.content-container div.content-element-container > div.loading-container")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='content-container']//div[@class='content-element-container']/div[@class='loading-container']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```